# Copy non-referenced projects from solution to the solution's startup-project

Tags: .net, msbuild, prism

Is there anyway to copy the ouput of projects to the bin folder of the current startup-project from the solution? Is it even possible to know which project is the startup project from within a MSBuild script? The projects I am speaking of are PRISM modules and due to their modularity, they aren't referenced by the shell project. However, we still add them to our solution.

Until now, we had a pretty neat solution to debug our application. Our Infrastructure project (which is the at lowest level of the build process) would delete a ...Shell\bin\Debug\Modules folder. This application's bootstrapper is configured to load modules directly from the "Modules" directory. All module-projects have their OutputPath configured to this folder.

This build process has the advantage that we can choose which modules we want to debug by simply Loading/Unloading the project. The modules folder is always emptied at the start and only loaded projects are built. This is a configuration-free way of debugging different mix of modules.

How, we started a new PRISM Project that uses modules we have already created for the other Shell. Now I face the problem that this comfortable setup cannot work anymore. A single module project has a fixed OutputPath and developers wouldn't be able to reuse the projects in different solutions without problems.

Btw, it musn't be an MSBuild script, but is must be automated.

Edit: I forgot to stress the point that the same idea should work with multiple Prism Shells using common modules and that I can work on multiple PRISM Products simultaneously. That why I can't used a shared Output Path for all folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify an `AfterBuild` Target in MSBuild to copy the outputs of other projects like this:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
   <Copy SourceFiles="$(SolutionDir)MyProject1\bin\$(Configuration)\*.dll" DestinationFolder="$(TargetDir)"/>
   <!-- repeat for other projects -->
</Target>
```

AFAIK, finding out the startup project is not trivial as that info is stored in .suo file. You can explore writing your own MSBuild task or extending [MSBuild Community task: GetSolutionProjects](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/)

Answer (score 1):

You could configure the OutputPath of your "new" project to point to the same ...Shell\bin\Debug folder as your "shell" application. That way the new application can again load its modules from the very same Modules folder. No changes to any other part of the system are required.

Comment: I edit edited my question: I forgot to stress the point that the same idea should work with multiple Prism Shells using common modules and that I can work on multiple PRISM Products simultaneously. That why I can't use a shared Output Path for all folders.

Comment: Does that mean you want to be able to have a different set of "active" modules for each product? (And I obviously need to read up on Prism to see why a shared output path won't work.)

Comment: @Gerstendörfer: Yes. In a nutshell, I want to have the same development experience you get when you reference projects, but without referencing it.

Comment: @Gerstendörfer: late EDIT OF previous comment: Yes. In a nutshell, I want to have the same development experience you get when you reference projects with "Copy local" = true, but without referencing it. This is what I exactly need for the loosely coupled module projects. It needs to copy [Module]/bin/Debug automatically to the [Startup-project]/bin/Debug/Modules Folder. This must be implemented in such a way that a developer that gets the solution via repository doesn't need to setup anything on his local machine.

Comment: For a moment I thought something to this effect may be possible using project references with the `<ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>` metadata set, but it doesn't work well with unloading referenced projects. I still think a common output directory for the startup projects (shells) with a common modules subdirectory is your best bet; modifying the shells to support this if necessary. Different sets of active modules could be supported by getting multiple copies of the solution from source control.